# Is it possible to choose unique different exit-nodes for Tor?

Tags: configuration, exit-relays

I want to run 2 (or more) tor instances on the same machine
each one on different port,but i want to make sure that those 2 instance will never have the same exit node or ip at the same time

i am thinking of using  `ExitNodes node,node,…` in torrc file,but i don't know how to choose unique  nodes for each instance (without the country )

for example `ExitNodes 1,2,3,4,.....,100` for the first instance

and `ExitNodes 100,101,102,.....200` for the second one

i can't find any informations about the fingerprints of nodes,only the country codes

why doesn't tor identify each node with a unique id

Comment: FYI the anonymity analysis of tor depends heavily on all clients building circuits using the same algorithms. If you are building circuits in a different way than other people, this could theoretically be used to deanonymize you.

Comment: i am just looking to get different exit nodes for each instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor does indeed identify each node with a unique ID, which is called *finerprint*.

You can get the fingerprints of some exit nodes via [Globe](https://globe.torproject.org/#/search/query=flag%3Aexit). Currently, the limit of results is set to 50, so you'd have to use finer queries if you want more exit nodes.

You can then use these fingerprints with the `ExitNodes` entry in the torrc of one tor instance and block them with the `ExcludeExitNodes` entry in the other torrc.

Comment: ok thank you,and how many instant can i connect to from 1 ip adress ? is it true that it is limited only to 2 connections per ip ? or it is unlimited

Comment: afaik, you can run as many _clients_ as you want on a given IP. The limit is only for relays.